# MySQL connecting to PythonAnywhere error 2003

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector, pythonanywhere

I'm using pycharm. I already have the SSH tunnel, I just need to connect it but i always get the same error:

```py
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="i know it.mysql.eu.pythonanywhere-services.com",
    user="i know it",
    port=3306,
    password="i know it",
    database="i know it"
)
```

Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%-.100s:%u' (%s) (Warning: %u format: a real number is required, not str)
```

Comment: Not familiar with PyCharm enough -- is it wrapping your connection with a tunnel manager?  The connection has to be run in the context of tunnel.  Also -- SSH is a paid feature on PA, if you have a free account it won't work.

Comment: If you've set up an SSH tunnel then you should be connecting to the local end of that tunnel in your code, so the `host` should be `localhost`, not the PythonAnywhere hostname.